# Upload file using Jenkins Active Choices Reactive References plugin

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-groovy

I am using Jenkins Active Choice plugin. I want to provide a file upload function based on reference  variable
The below setting allows me to enter  text when i select reference parameter scan_type as vulnerability-Web
[image]

What i want is , instead of taking text input it should upload file , and content of the file should be assigned to SELENIUM_RECORDED_FILE

I tried using below groovy

```
if (scan_type.equals("Vulnerability-Web")) {
inputBox = "<body> <form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> Select file to upload: <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'> </form>"
return inputBox
}
```

its adding file upload option but the file content is not stored in SELENIUM_RECORDED_FILE

[image]

Please let me know how can we achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Reading through [HERE](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-38893), it looks like you must have

```html
<input type="file" name="file">
```